# Can I some how make 2nd task run automatically after completion of first task in aws fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I cannot run my second task until first task is completed and first task completion time varies every day. Is there anyway that task 2 can keep listening to task 1 and as soon as it task 1 completes then task 2 will start automatically without scheduling.

Right now I have added schedule. But my first task is taking more time than expected for some runs.

Comment: Have you considered Step Functions. The solution is designed to handle complex workflows, running a sequence of functions is part of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.